# Detecting circular dependencies in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've implemented a service container which is able to create services by resolving them via `reflect-metadata`. Speaking in code:

```
// The services
@Service()
export class Bar {
  constructor() { console.log('i am bar'); }
}

@Service()
export class Foo {
  constructor(bar: Bar) {}
}

// Creating an instance for Foo
Container.get<Foo>('foo');
```

This results in a resolved instance of Foo with a correctly injected instance of `Bar`.

But things got pretty confusing when trying to detect circular dependencies:

```
@Service()
export class Foo {
  constructor(b: Bar) {}
}

@Service()
export class Bar {
  constructor(f: Foo) {}
}

Container.get<Foo>('foo'); // returns Foo, but not with an injected Bar instance
```

Interestingly `Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target)` for `Foo` returns `undefined`. As soon as the circular dependency is changed to something non-circular the correct types are returned again.

Container implementation might be irrelevant here, but it might be interesting to see the `Service` decorator:

```
export const Service = () : ClassDecorator => {
  return (target: any): void => {
    console.log(Reflect.getMetadata(DESIGN_PARAM_TYPES, target));
  }
};
```

This logs `undefined` as soon dependencies become circular, but correctly returns the required types otherwise.

My goal is to throw a proper exception on circular dependencies - but it's impossible for me to detect right now. Why? And how to fix this?

Comment: I feel like that's a bug with reflect-metadata. The only way I know for detecting circular dependencies using in the types is to examine the AST. Using my library [ts-simple-ast](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-simple-ast), you could build a graph of all the dependencies between classes and then throw when a circular reference occurs. Alternatively, there might be a way to add a test that runs through all the classes and throws when undefined is returned for `design:paramtypes`. I'm not sure if it's possible using only reflect-metadata... I don't know enough about it.

Comment: Did you find the solution

Comment: I throw exceptions in this case, suggesting that there's a circular dependency.

Answer (score -1):

Current workaround, since I haven't found a solution to this:

When injecting services I check for `undefined` and throw a `ServiceResolvingFailedException`. Not exactly what I wanted, but at least some way to tell the dev what happened.