# How to detect circular dependency in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, reflect-metadata

The code below has a circular dependency issue. A -> B -> A

## Reproducible problem:

/a.ts

```
import {B} from './b';
import { Service } from './test';
@Service
export class A {
    static id = 'A'

    constructor(b: B) {
    }
}
```

/b.ts

```
import {A} from './a';
import { Service } from './test';
@Service
export class B {
    static id = 'B'
    constructor(a: A) {
    }
}
```

/test.ts

```
export function Service(target: any) {
// purposefully empty 
}
```

/index.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import {A} from './a'
import {B} from './b'

const paramTypesA = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', A);
const paramTypesB = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', B);


console.log('paramTypesA is', paramTypesA)
console.log('paramTypesB is', paramTypesB)
```

## Expected output

```
paramTypesA is [ [Function: B] { id: 'B' } ]
paramTypesA is [ [Function: A] { id: 'A' } ]
```

## Actual output

```
paramTypesA is [ [Function: B] { id: 'B' } ]
paramTypesB is [ undefined ]
```

## Question: How to achieve the expected output

The goal is to detect circular dependency. But we also want to know what parameter exactly causes the circular dependency.

If reflect-metadata only output undefined, it is impossible to know which parameter provokes the circular dependency.

I already checked [Detecting circular dependencies in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48080152/detecting-circular-dependencies-in-typescript) but this didn't help

Comment: what output will be if you change the order of imports? So swap import A and B.

Comment: I tried that already and the the actual output is `paramTypesA is [ undefined ]
paramTypesB is [ [Function: A] { id: 'A' } ] ` . The expected output however should still be paramTypesA is `[ [Function: B] { id: 'B' } ]
paramTypesA is [ [Function: A] { id: 'A' } ]`

Comment: In that case, it seems to me that TS is OK with that circular dependency. So, the problem is inside `reflect-metadata`.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you, because you said "the goal is to detect circular dependency": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462055/detect-circular-dependencies-in-es6